# CSS Scroll Snap Aligns to Second Div on Page Load - How to Prevent This?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm currently working with CSS Scroll Snap and I've come across an unusual behavior. My page automatically scrolls to the second div when it loads.

Here is the structure of my code:

```
<div
  style={{
    height: "100vh",
    overflowY: "scroll",
    scrollSnapType: "y mandatory",
  }}
>
  <div
    style={{
      height: "100vh",
      backgroundColor: "red",
    }}
  ></div>
  <div
    style={{
      height: "100vh",
      backgroundColor: "green",
      scrollSnapAlign: "start",
    }}
  ></div>
  <div
    style={{
      height: "100vh",
      backgroundColor: "blue",
      scrollSnapAlign: "start",
    }}
  ></div>
</div>
```

I've observed this behavior across multiple browsers and there's no other JavaScript or CSS code that should affect the scroll position on load.

My question is, why is the page automatically scrolling to the second div when it loads? Is there a way to prevent this behavior without adding scrollSnapAlign: start; to the first div?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is normal behaviour, as shown here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-snap-align. I'm not sure what you want to achieve or create, so I can't help further.